Alternative xDB Shard Splitting Procedure
Perhaps this isn't directly a Sitecore issue, but was hoping someone had experience.
We currently have 2 shards for our Sitecore installation in an Azure DB.  Our Shards have grown pretty large and I would like to split them.
There is a complication, however. Sitecore's instructions require the user of the Azure split/merge service Microsoft is shutting down Cloud Services (now referred to as "Classic") at the end of this month.
The Azure Split/merge service has not been upgraded to Cloud services (extended support) and it seems Microsoft has no intention of doing so.
I did put in a support ticket with Sitecore and they plan on updating the instructions to avoid the issue, but they have put a low priority on this.
Just in case this helps, our Azure installation uses AKS (should there be a way to deploy that way).  I had thought about using the DLLs from the split/merge project and sort of re-implementing the 2 web services in the configuration, but I thought that might be both overkill and risky.  For reference, we are currently on Sitecore XP 10.2, but it seems the instructions are the same up through 10.4.  Any help would be appreciated.

Microsoft ended up providing alternative instructions for the Split/Merge service using Azure App Services.  Was able to use this to create a localized docker setup to accomodate and was able to follow the instructions to split.
